# telerik:RadCalendar does not focus on set date

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I'm using a RadCalendar on a WebForm. this is my RadCalendar:

```
 <telerik:RadCalendar RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadCalendar1" Width="100%"
 EnableMultiSelect="false" EnableKeyboardNavigation="true"
 ShowColumnHeaders="true" ShowDayCellToolTips="true" ShowRowHeaders="true" runat="server">
 <FastNavigationSettings EnableTodayButtonSelection="true">
<ShowAnimation Type="Slide" Duration="2" /></FastNavigationSettings></telerik:RadCalendar>
```

I want to set RadCalendar from a DataTable using c#. I could succeed in my purpose using following code on `Page_Load`:

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         DataTable dt = cls.PhotoFetchById(ViewState["photoId"].ToString());
         if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
              string date = dt.Rows[0]["phDate"].ToString();
              RadCalendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(date);

          }
    }
```

The problem is RadCalander always show current month page and if the set date is no place in current month page, it's never shown on page loading.
For example, if the set date is "2013-02-12" but the current date is "2018/11/23", RadCalendar always show current month page without any selected day.

Comment: if I remember correctly `RadCalendar` has a method `GoToDate()` or `NavigateToDate()` where you can pass your `DateTime.Parse(date)` and it will navigate to it

Answer (score 1):

It looks you also need to set **FocusedDate** to your date as well.

[Source](https://www.telerik.com/forums/radcalendar-selecteddate-is-not-working)